# Crossdomain form authentication (using WebClient and cookies)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, webclient, mobile-application

I have 2 sites, the first site is basic forms authentication system and some method, that needs to authenticate user. In the second I use modified WebClient (it can use cookies) and send request for authenticate and after request for secure operation. At first step all are OK, first server return AUTH cookie in response and remember it, and on the second it send request for secure operation with AUTH cookie, but at the first site, our request is not authorized! `Request.isauthenticated = false`.

Why is it? The AUTH cookie at this request are valid.

It is code for site №1 WebClient requests.

```
//Create an instance of your new CookieAware Web Client
var client = new CookieAwareWebClient();

//Authenticate (username and password can be either hard-coded or pulled from a settings area)
var values = new NameValueCollection { { "Name", "name" }, { "Password", "1234" } };

//Perform authentication - after this has been performed the cookie will be stored within the Web Client
client.UploadValues(new Uri("http://localhost:15536/Plugins/ProductListGetter/login"), "POST", values);
var _cookies = client.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"];

client.UploadString(new Uri("http://localhost:15536/Plugins/ProductListGetter/ChangeNameForCurrentUser"), "POST", "Example Message");
client.UploadString(new Uri("http://localhost:15536/Plugins/ProductListGetter/ChangeNameForCurrentUser"), "POST", "Example Message");
client.Dispose();
```

And code for modified WebClient

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    //Properties to handle implementing a timeout
    private int? _timeout = null;
    public int? Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeout;
        }
        set
        {
            _timeout = value;
        }
    }

    //A CookieContainer class to house the Cookie once it is contained within one of the Requests
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    //Constructor
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    //Method to handle setting the optional timeout (in milliseconds)
    public void SetTimeout(int timeout)
    {
        _timeout = timeout;
    }

    //This handles using and storing the Cookie information as well as managing the Request timeout
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        //Handles the CookieContainer
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        //Sets the Timeout if it exists
        if (_timeout.HasValue)
        {
            request.Timeout = _timeout.Value;
        }
        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Resolved with cookieless="UseCookies"